# setTimeout in React after render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first question. Anyway, I am new to React, I started 2 weeks ago.
I am making a flipbook where `updateAll` updates all `allPages` in the book.

The problem is that when the page is flipped, the z-index needs to be changed in order to adhere to the correct stacking.

When flipping right, we see the z-index of the page on the right change too quickly, and the flipping isn't smooth. Go check it out yourself to see what I mean.

https://cookbookreact.netlify.app/

I need to use setTimeout to set the z-index 200 milliseconds after the page is flipped, so that the page flipping is smooth. But how? I know I need to use useEffect() I think. Right?

Whenever I try to use useEffect(), it says I am breaking the rules of hooks, so I don't even know what to do.

The last z-index needs to be updated so that we can scroll on that page by the way.

```
   // we update any pages that were flipped
    updateAll((prevAllPages) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
        // flip current page
        prevAllPages[pageNum + i].isFlipped =
          !prevAllPages[pageNum + i].isFlipped;
        // zIndex

        prevAllPages[pageNum + i].zIndex =
          999 + prevAllPages[pageNum + i].pageNum;
      }

      return prevAllPages;
    });

    /*** Set timeout goes here ***/

    setTimeout(function () {
      // so that last page can be seen
      updateAll((prevAllPages) => {
        if (pageNum < maxPages / 2) {
          prevAllPages[pageNum + amount].zIndex =
            999 + prevAllPages[pageNum + amount].pageNum;
        }

        return prevAllPages;
      });

      // then we update the page number
      updatePageNum((prevPageNum) => {
        return prevPageNum + amount;
      });
    }, 200);
```

I'd appreciate any help, Thank you

David

Answer (score 0):

When updating state try creating a new variable to return instead of changing the prevAllPages and returning it again.

Comment: This did not work. Should I make a deep copy you mean?

Comment: Nevermind, it worked after messing around with the code. Thank you!

Comment: would be great if you market it as an answer :D